# Python Opencv Reduce Colors to RGB Only

Tags: python, opencv, colors

I'm trying to take a RGB image and reduce the colors in it to only contain red (255, 0, 0) green (0, 255, 0) and blue (0, 0, 255). I've written a simple function to do this for me but it seems very inefficient.

```
def colorReduce(image):
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    for x in range(h):
        for y in range(w):
            px = image[x][y]
            c = np.argmax(px)
            px = [0, 0, 0]
            px[c]=255
            image[x][y] = px
```

Do any of you have any ideas for a faster method for this? I know opencv has cv2.kmeans, but that too is not very efficient as it's a lot more powerful than what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is an even faster method than this at the end of the answer which uses `np.searchsorted()`.

You should be able to use vectorised Numpy for this if you run your `argmax()` across the third dimension, i.e. across the colour channels.

Something like this:

```
# Make array of brightest colour index
m = np.argmax(im, axis=2)

# Make empty results array same shape as original image
res = np.zeros_like(im)

# Where blue is the brightest, make result blue
res[m==0] = [255,0,0]

# Where green is the brightest, make result green
res[m==1] = [0,255,0]

# Where blue is the brightest, make result blue
res[m==2] = [0,0,255]
```

---

I think this is more succinct:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('colorwheel.jpg')

# Find index of brightest channel at each point
m = np.argmax(im,axis=2) 

# Set up possible choices for output colour
choices = [[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255]]

# Choose one of the 3 colours based on whichever was brightest
res = np.choose(m[...,np.newaxis],choices)

# Save
cv2.imwrite('result.png',res)
```

Input image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

---

Note that it is actually 3-6x faster to use `np.searchsorted()` than `np.choose()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

def palette2RGB(image, palette):
    indices = np.arange(0, len(palette))
    out = palette[np.searchsorted(indices, image)]
    return out


palette = np.array([
    [255,   0,   0],   # red
    [  0, 255,   0],   # green
    [  0,   0, 255],   # blue
    [255, 255, 255],   # white
    [  0,   0,   0]])  # black

# Make a repeatable random image 2 rows, 4 columns of palette indices
np.random.seed(0)
image = np.random.randint(0, len(palette), (2,4))

print(image)
# array([[4, 0, 3, 3],
#        [3, 1, 3, 2]])

res = palette2RGB(image,palette) 
print(res)
#array([[[  0,   0,   0],
#        [255,   0,   0],
#        [255, 255, 255],
#        [255, 255, 255]],
#
#       [[255, 255, 255],
#        [  0, 255,   0],
#        [255, 255, 255],
#        [  0,   0, 255]]])
```

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, simple quantisation, apply colour map, palette, LUT, lookup, np.choose, np.searchsorted.

Comment: Neat!. You could use `res = np.zeros_like(img)` as it is simpler

Comment: @fmw42 Indeed I should, thanks. There must be a way to avoid 3 passes as well and use `m` to index `res` but I can't see it for the minute, something like `res[:,:,m] = 255`